# Disabling jsessionid in url in java GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsessionid

I have one problem with jsessionid in url. i want only to use jsessionid with cookies, but i tried everything including adding this to web.xml.

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Any idea how to solve thisone?

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: Sadly no. :( I tried everything.

Comment: well i found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678810/jsessionid-gets-appended-to-the-url-when-running-gae-devserver/19690688#19690688

Answer (score 0):

Use servlet 3.0 version and add this to the `web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: It seems like gae doesn't support servlet 3.0. I am using sdk 1.7.5