# jsessionID gets appended to the url when running GAE devserver

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, jsessionid, devserver

For some reason string like: `;jsessionid=SESSION_HERE` gets added to urls when I visit my app deployed to GAE devserver.

This messes things up since for some of the urls it cannot be parsed as as a GET parameter at all (sometimes it ends up with urls like: `http://localhost:8080/someurl;jsessionid=0000`).

My webapp configuraion is trivial and I use maven and `appengine-maven-plugin` to run devserver like this:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

What is the reason of this and how this can be removed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionURL</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

... to your `web.xml`. Read more on this in [jetty session documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150502064407/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/SessionIds).

Note: GAE is running on Jetty 6.1. In anyone experiences the same problem with a newer Jetty version, the configuration parameter is named differently, see [Jetty 9 session management](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-management.html):

> - `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName`
> - **jsessionid**
> - Session URL parameter name. Defaults to jsessionid, but can be set for a particular webapp with this context param. Set to "none" to disable URL rewriting.